# installing project on clean database

Tags: magento2, setup-upgrade

I have created data patch
It was working fine locally

`Unable to apply data patch Devall\SpecialPrice\Setup\Patch\Data\AddLabaCenaAttribute for module Devall_SpecialPrice. Original exception message: Notice: Undefined index: entity_type_id in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-eav/Setup/EavSetup.php on line 1097`

now when setup:upgrading, have this error.
What can be the problem
I am using 2.3.3 magento

`$this->eavSetupFactory->updateAttribute(4, 184, 'is_used_for_promo_rules', 1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used clean database so module changed its ID, that was the problem.